# 3d array traversal originating from center

Tags: arrays, algorithm, 3d, gpu

I'm trying to find a traversal order for a 3d array with uniform dimension `n`.The traversal order should hereby be sorted ascending by it's distance to the cube's center (order of cells with equal indices is arbitrary).
Example for a 2d-Array:

```
7 4 8
3 0 1
6 2 5
```

Which basically is the distance in [Manhattan metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry):

```
2 1 2
1 0 1
2 1 2
```

Traversal as relative coordinates with respect to the origin:

```
[ 0, 0]
[ 1, 0]
[ 0,-1]
[-1, 0]
[ 0, 1]
[ 1,-1]
[-1,-1]
[-1, 1]
[ 1, 1]
```

I know of some ways to solve this, for instance precalculating all indices and sorting them according to their distance to the origin. However, since this algorithm is intended to perform on **GPU**, there are some restrictions:

1. **No recursion** (I'm aware of the possibility resolving recursion into
   an iterative algorithm - maintaining a stack is however not a
   suitable solution in my experience)
2. **No offline calculation** (= calculation on the CPU and transferring the result to the GPU). The solution needs to be as flexible as
   possible

While searching for solutions I stumbled upon this question, which is exactly the problem I tend to solve, the accepted answer albeit envolves a tree structure, which does not fit the specified requirements: [3D Array Traversal in Different Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24107769/3d-array-traversal-in-different-order)

I also thought of a way to create the indices using spherical coordinates, which unfortunately does not yield the correct order. What is an appropriate algorithm to generate the given traversal order for 3d-arrays?

Edit: [Stormwind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37214057/3d-array-traversal-originating-from-center#comment62309835_37398736) provided an excellent alternative description for the given Problem: "[The problem] is actually about converting addressing from one space to another. Converting between a 1-dimensional and 2-dimensional is simple, like 1,2,3,... to (1,1),(1,2)(2,1)... But this is more like converting from an ascending 1-dimensional (or at least square) to an "ascending octahedron layered" space, when "ascending" means "innermost layer first" in addition to an existing (though arbitrary) incrementing order at each layer surface."

Comment: Is the traversal order only determined by the distance to the center? Because then in your 2D example any ordering which has 0 in the center would be correct. Or are you specifically looking for a "spiral" type traversal order, where you always move to a neighbouring cell?

Comment: @m69 Yes the order is only determined by the distance but the example was wrong, I updated the question. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: is `N` always odd or can be also even ? The distance is euclidean or manhatan ?

Comment: @Spektre N can be both. The distance is Manhattan.

Comment: @Dual: It matters rather a lot if the distance is not the standard Euclidean distance. You should update the question.

Comment: I'm not sure that order of cells at equal distance is irrelevant. If your have a real 3D array of considerable size, and you have to read its elements during traversal, then different traversals may have different behavior with respect to cache or coaslescing.
E.g. if you visit all equally distant cells in random order, that would trash caches even on CPU.
What is layout of your 3D array in memory? Is it like `idx(x, y, z) = x*n^2 + y*n + z`?

Comment: How is the desired `traversal order` to be represented? (And please do put relevant information (like metric used) in the question proper.)

Comment: @greybeard The metric is implicitly given by the traversal order. I will however update the question accordingly.

Comment: As you say the problem must be solved on the GPU, are you talking about using shaders and floating point surfaces? GPGPU?

Comment: Lots of good and well written answers - for the CPU! Would you kindly evaluate how the proposed answers (or the accepted one) can perform on the GPU?

Comment: I agree. This searched "algorithm" is just a very small part of a greater project which has not been evaluated performance wise, but the solution given in the accepted answer does not add too much overhead to the rest of the calculation. But the execution might probably suffer from branch and data divergence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[I'm using the [Manhattan distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) in the solution]

For simplicity, let start assuming 3D arrays of odd dimension (`[2N+1, 2N+1, 2N+1]`)

Using *manhattan distance* the greatest distance between the center (`[0,0,0]`) and a point is `3N` (`[N,N,N]`, [`N,N,-N`], ...)

So, basically the idea is find a way to generate all coordinates that have a specific distance. Then starting from distance `0` to `3N` generating those coordinates.

To generate coordinates `[X,Y,Z]` that distance to center in some value `K`, what we need is all numbers `X`, `Y`, `Z` between `-N` and `N` such that `ABS(X) + ABS(Y) + ABS(Z) == K`. This can be done with this:

```
FUNC COORDS_AT_DIST(K)
    FOR X = -MIN(N, K) TO MIN(N, K)
        FOR Y = -MIN(N, K - ABS(X)) TO MIN(N, K - ABS(X))
            LET Z = K - ABS(X) - ABS(Y)
            IF Z <= N
                VISIT(X, Y, Z)
                IF Z != 0
                    VISIT(X, Y, -Z)
```

Then, use this function like so:

```
FOR K = 0 TO 3N
    COORDS_AT_DIST(K)
```

This code visit all coordinates with values between `[-N,-N,-N]` and `[N,N,N]` sorted according to the distance to `[0,0,0]`.

Now, to handle even dimensions too, we need some extra checks since the values in coordinates for a dimension `L` goes between `[-(L/2-1),-(L/2-1),-(L/2-1)]` and `[L/2,L/2,L/2]`.

Something like this:

```
FUNC VISIT_COORDS_FOR_DIM(L)
    LET N = L/2               //Integer division
    FOR K = 0 TO 3N
        FOR X = -MIN(N - REM(L+1, 2), K) TO MIN(N, K)
            FOR Y = -MIN(N - REM(L+1, 2), K - ABS(X)) TO MIN(N, K - ABS(X))
                LET Z = K - ABS(X) - ABS(Y)
                IF Z <= N
                    VISIT(X, Y, Z)
                    IF Z != 0 && (REM(L, 2) != 0 || Z < N)
                        VISIT(X, Y, -Z)
```

Just for clarity:

```
MIN(X, Y): Minimum value between X and Y
ABS(X): Absolute value of X
REM(X, Y): Remainder after division of X by Y

VISIT(X, Y, Z): Visit the generated coordinate (X, Y, Z)
```

Using `VISIT_COORDS_FOR_DIM` function with `L=3` you get this:

```
 1. [0, 0, 0]       DISTANCE: 0
 2. [-1, 0, 0]      DISTANCE: 1
 3. [0, -1, 0]      DISTANCE: 1
 4. [0, 0, -1]      DISTANCE: 1
 5. [0, 0, 1]       DISTANCE: 1
 6. [0, 1, 0]       DISTANCE: 1
 7. [1, 0, 0]       DISTANCE: 1
 8. [-1, -1, 0]     DISTANCE: 2
 9. [-1, 0, -1]     DISTANCE: 2
10. [-1, 0, 1]      DISTANCE: 2
11. [-1, 1, 0]      DISTANCE: 2
12. [0, -1, -1]     DISTANCE: 2
13. [0, -1, 1]      DISTANCE: 2
14. [0, 1, -1]      DISTANCE: 2
15. [0, 1, 1]       DISTANCE: 2
16. [1, -1, 0]      DISTANCE: 2
17. [1, 0, -1]      DISTANCE: 2
18. [1, 0, 1]       DISTANCE: 2
19. [1, 1, 0]       DISTANCE: 2
20. [-1, -1, -1]    DISTANCE: 3
21. [-1, -1, 1]     DISTANCE: 3
22. [-1, 1, -1]     DISTANCE: 3
23. [-1, 1, 1]      DISTANCE: 3
24. [1, -1, -1]     DISTANCE: 3
25. [1, -1, 1]      DISTANCE: 3
26. [1, 1, -1]      DISTANCE: 3
27. [1, 1, 1]       DISTANCE: 3
```

And for `L=4`:

```
 1. [0, 0, 0]      DISTANCE: 0                    33. [1, -1, -1]    DISTANCE: 3
 2. [-1, 0, 0]     DISTANCE: 1                    34. [1, -1, 1]     DISTANCE: 3
 3. [0, -1, 0]     DISTANCE: 1                    35. [1, 0, 2]      DISTANCE: 3
 4. [0, 0, -1]     DISTANCE: 1                    36. [1, 1, -1]     DISTANCE: 3
 5. [0, 0, 1]      DISTANCE: 1                    37. [1, 1, 1]      DISTANCE: 3
 6. [0, 1, 0]      DISTANCE: 1                    38. [1, 2, 0]      DISTANCE: 3
 7. [1, 0, 0]      DISTANCE: 1                    39. [2, -1, 0]     DISTANCE: 3
 8. [-1, -1, 0]    DISTANCE: 2                    40. [2, 0, -1]     DISTANCE: 3
 9. [-1, 0, -1]    DISTANCE: 2                    41. [2, 0, 1]      DISTANCE: 3
10. [-1, 0, 1]     DISTANCE: 2                    42. [2, 1, 0]      DISTANCE: 3
11. [-1, 1, 0]     DISTANCE: 2                    43. [-1, -1, 2]    DISTANCE: 4
12. [0, -1, -1]    DISTANCE: 2                    44. [-1, 1, 2]     DISTANCE: 4
13. [0, -1, 1]     DISTANCE: 2                    45. [-1, 2, -1]    DISTANCE: 4
14. [0, 0, 2]      DISTANCE: 2                    46. [-1, 2, 1]     DISTANCE: 4
15. [0, 1, -1]     DISTANCE: 2                    47. [0, 2, 2]      DISTANCE: 4
16. [0, 1, 1]      DISTANCE: 2                    48. [1, -1, 2]     DISTANCE: 4
17. [0, 2, 0]      DISTANCE: 2                    49. [1, 1, 2]      DISTANCE: 4
18. [1, -1, 0]     DISTANCE: 2                    50. [1, 2, -1]     DISTANCE: 4
19. [1, 0, -1]     DISTANCE: 2                    51. [1, 2, 1]      DISTANCE: 4
20. [1, 0, 1]      DISTANCE: 2                    52. [2, -1, -1]    DISTANCE: 4
21. [1, 1, 0]      DISTANCE: 2                    53. [2, -1, 1]     DISTANCE: 4
23. [2, 0, 0]      DISTANCE: 2                    54. [2, 0, 2]      DISTANCE: 4
23. [-1, -1, -1]   DISTANCE: 3                    55. [2, 1, -1]     DISTANCE: 4
24. [-1, -1, 1]    DISTANCE: 3                    56. [2, 1, 1]      DISTANCE: 4
25. [-1, 0, 2]     DISTANCE: 3                    57. [2, 2, 0]      DISTANCE: 4
26. [-1, 1, -1]    DISTANCE: 3                    58. [-1, 2, 2]     DISTANCE: 5
27. [-1, 1, 1]     DISTANCE: 3                    59. [1, 2, 2]      DISTANCE: 5
28. [-1, 2, 0]     DISTANCE: 3                    60. [2, -1, 2]     DISTANCE: 5
29. [0, -1, 2]     DISTANCE: 3                    61. [2, 1, 2]      DISTANCE: 5
30. [0, 1, 2]      DISTANCE: 3                    62. [2, 2, -1]     DISTANCE: 5
31. [0, 2, -1]     DISTANCE: 3                    63. [2, 2, 1]      DISTANCE: 5
32. [0, 2, 1]      DISTANCE: 3                    64. [2, 2, 2]      DISTANCE: 6
```

This solution has as benefits that no requires any special data-structure, not even an array.

---

Another solution could be if you can use a queue (it is not hard to implement with an array) and 3D boolean (or int) array is do like a BFS starting from the center.

Firstly, to define what is a neighbor, you can use movement arrays, for example:

- Two cells are neighbors if share a common side ([Manhattan distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry)):

  ```
   DX = { 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0 }
   DY = { 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0 }
   DZ = { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1 }
  ```
- Two cells are neighbors if share a common edge:

  ```
   DX = { 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1, 0 }
   DY = { 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 1, -1, 0, -1 }
   DZ = { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1 }
  ```
- Two cells are neighbors if share a common corner ([Chebyshev distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_distance)):

  ```
   DX = { 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1 }
   DY = { 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 1, -1, 0, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1 }
   DZ = { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1 }
  ```

Now, using a queue you can start from center position, then add the neighbors, then neighbors of the neighbors and so on. In each iteration you can visit each generated position.

Something like this:

```
DX = { 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0 }
DY = { 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0 }
DZ = { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1 }

VISIT_COORDS_FOR_DIM(L):
    LET N = L/2
    IF (REM(L, 2) == 0)
        N--

    V: BOOLEAN[L, L, L]
    Q: QUEUE<POINT3D>

    V[N, N, N] = TRUE
    ENQUEUE(Q, POINT3D(N, N, N))

    WHILE COUNT(Q) > 0
        P = DEQUEUE(Q)
        VISIT(P.X - N, P.Y - N, P.Z - N) //To Transform coords to [-N, N] range.

        FOR I = 0 TO LENGTH(DX) - 1
            LET X = P.X + DX[I]
            LET Y = P.Y + DY[I]
            LET Z = P.Z + DZ[I]

            IF IS_VALID_POS(L, X, Y, Z) && V[X, Y, Z] == FALSE
                V[X, Y, Z] = TRUE
                ENQUEUE(Q, POINT3D(X, Y, Z))

IS_VALID_POS(L, X, Y, Z)
    RETURN X >= 0 && X < L &&
           Y >= 0 && Y < L &&
           Z >= 0 && Z < L
```

Used functions:

```
REM(X, Y): Remainder after division of X by Y
ENQUEUE(Q, X): Enqueue element X in queue Q
DEQUEUE(Q): Dequeue first element from queue Q
COUNT(Q): Number of elements in queue Q 

VISIT(X, Y, Z): Visit the generated coordinate (X, Y, Z)
```

This solution has as benefits that you can define when two position are neighbors using movement arrays.

Comment: @Dual: if you need an implementation in a concrete language, please tell me.

Comment: If the cube has even sides, what does a zero coordinate signify?

Comment: @DaveGalvin: You need to define if it's in the first or the second half, in my case zero coordinates is the last position of the first half.

Comment: The first solution is the answer I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: @Dual You could have saved him the trouble of coming up with the second solution :-)

Comment: @m69 other people with a similar problem could however profit from the second solution. So no harm done ;)

Answer (score 7):

After thinking for a while I've came up with an idea to represent 3d array as a sequence of nodes with directions: `+i`, `-i`, `+j`, `-j`, `+k`, `-k`.

### Approach

For 2-dimensional array it would be sufficient to have only three rules:

1. Each iteration over each node moves it along its axis in its direction, i.e. node `+j` will increment 2nd index, node `-i` will decrement 1st index.
2. There are two kinds of nodes: `Main` and `Secondary`. Main axis have one index `0`. Each iteration over `Main` `i` and `j` axis nodes (I'll call them `I` and `J`) produces `Secondary` node rotated clockwise 90 degrees:

   - `+I -> -j`
   - `-J -> -i`
   - `-I -> +j`
   - `+J -> +i`
3. Each node has lifetime which decrements every iteration. Lifetime of the node equals `(n-1)/2` for odd values of `n` (for even values see code below). After lifetime goes to 0 the node should be removed.

To enable 3rd dimension another rule should be applied:

4. Third type of nodes with direction along `k` axis (here - depth) produces set of `I` and `J` axis in each iteration:

   - `+K -> +I, -J, -I, +J`
   - `-K -> +I, -J, -I, +J`

Here is how it will look:

[image: 3D array]

With such approach elemnts will be automatically sorted by [Manhattan distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) as in Arturo Menchaca solution.

### Implementation

Here is python code that does what I've described. There is a lot of space for improvements this is just a proof of concept. It has no sorting, no recursion and I don't see any offline calculations.
It also contains few tests. [<kbd>Run</kbd>](http://ideone.com/c3Daay)

```
NO = ( 0, 0, 0, 2, 0)
Pi = (+1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
PI = (+1, 0, 0, 0, 1)
Pj = ( 0,+1, 0, 0, 0)
PJ = ( 0,+1, 0, 0, 1)
PK = ( 0, 0,+1, 0, 2)
Mi = (-1, 0, 0, 1, 0)
MI = (-1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
Mj = ( 0,-1, 0, 1, 0)
MJ = ( 0,-1, 0, 1, 1)
MK = ( 0, 0,-1, 1, 2)
#      i  j  k  ^  ^
#               |  Id for comparison
#               Lifetime index

PRODUCE = {
    PI: [ Mj ], # +I -> -j
    MJ: [ Mi ], # -J -> -i
    MI: [ Pj ], # -I -> +j
    PJ: [ Pi ], # +J -> +i
    NO: [ NO ],
    Pi: [ NO ],
    Pj: [ NO ],
    Mi: [ NO ],
    Mj: [ NO ],
    PK: [ PI, MI, PJ, MJ ], # +K -> +I, -J, -I, +J
    MK: [ PI, MI, PJ, MJ ], # -K -> +I, -J, -I, +J
}


class Index:
    LastDistance = 0
    NumberOfVisits = 0
    MinIndex = 0
    MaxIndex = 0
    def __init__(self, i, j, k, lifetime, direction):
        self.globalLifetime = lifetime
        self.direction = direction

        # Assign parent's position
        self.i = i
        self.j = j
        self.k = k

        # Step away from parent
        self.lifetime = lifetime[direction[3]]
        self.step()

    def isLive(self):
        return self.lifetime > 0

    def visit(self):
        Index.NumberOfVisits += 1
        distance = self.distance()
        if distance < Index.LastDistance:
           raise NameError("Order is not preserved")
        Index.LastDistance = distance
        Index.MinIndex = min(self.i, Index.MinIndex)
        Index.MinIndex = min(self.j, Index.MinIndex)
        Index.MinIndex = min(self.k, Index.MinIndex)
        Index.MaxIndex = max(self.i, Index.MaxIndex)
        Index.MaxIndex = max(self.j, Index.MaxIndex)
        Index.MaxIndex = max(self.k, Index.MaxIndex)
        print("[{}, {}, {}]".format(self.i, self.j, self.k))

    def step(self):
        # Move in your direction
        self.i += self.direction[0]
        self.j += self.direction[1]
        self.k += self.direction[2]

    def iterate(self):
        self.lifetime -= 1

    def produce(self, result):
        for direction in PRODUCE[self.direction]:
            self.create(direction, result)

    def create(self, direction, result):
        index = Index(self.i, self.j, self.k, self.globalLifetime, direction)
        if index.isLive():
            result.append(index)

    def distance(self):
        # Manhattan Distance
        return abs(self.i) + abs(self.j) + abs(self.k)

def Traverse(N):
    TotalNumber = N*N*N
    halfA = halfB = (N-1)/2
    if N % 2 == 0:
        halfA = N/2
        halfB = N/2-1

    MinIndex = -min(halfB, halfA)
    MaxIndex = max(halfB, halfA)

    lifetime = (halfA, halfB, 0)

    SecondaryNodes = []
    MainNodes = []
    KNodes = []

    # visit center
    center = Index(0, 0, 0, lifetime, NO)
    center.visit()

    center.create(PI, MainNodes)
    center.create(MI, MainNodes)
    center.create(PJ, MainNodes)
    center.create(MJ, MainNodes)
    center.create(PK, KNodes)
    center.create(MK, KNodes)

    while len(SecondaryNodes) + len(MainNodes) + len(KNodes) > 0:

        # First - visit all side nodes
        temp = []
        for m in SecondaryNodes:
            m.visit()
            m.step()
            m.iterate()
            # Save node only if it is alive
            if m.isLive():
                temp.append(m)

        SecondaryNodes = temp

        # Second - visit all main nodes as they may produce secondary nodes
        temp = []
        for m in MainNodes:
            m.visit() # 1 - Visit
            m.produce(SecondaryNodes) # 2 - Produce second
            m.step() # 3 - Step 
            m.iterate() # 4 - Lose a life
            if m.isLive():
                temp.append(m)

        MainNodes = temp

        # Third - visit all K nodes as they may produce main nodes
        temp = []
        for m in KNodes:
            m.visit()
            m.produce(MainNodes)
            m.step()
            m.iterate()
            if m.isLive():
                temp.append(m)

        KNodes = temp
    if TotalNumber != Index.NumberOfVisits:
        raise NameError("Number of visited elements does not match {}/{}".format(Index.NumberOfVisits, TotalNumber))
    if MinIndex != Index.MinIndex:
        raise NameError("Minimal index is out of bounds {}/{}".format(Index.MinIndex, MinIndex))
    if MaxIndex != Index.MaxIndex:
        raise NameError("Maximal index is out of bounds {}/{}".format(Index.MaxIndex, MaxIndex))

Traverse(6)
```

### Implementation Simplified

Helper class to store index:

```
class Index:
    def __init__(self, i, j, k, lifetime):
        self.i = i
        self.j = j
        self.k = k
        self.lifetime = lifetime

    def visit(self):
        print("[{}, {}, {}]".format(self.i, self.j, self.k))
```

Set of functions to iterate `Main` nodes in proper direction:

```
def StepMainPlusI(mainPlusI, minusJ, lifetime):
    result = []
    for m in mainPlusI:
        if lifetime > 0:
            minusJ.append(Index(m.i, m.j-1, m.k, lifetime))
        m.lifetime -= 1
        m.i += 1
        if m.lifetime > 0:
            result.append(m)
    return result

def StepMainMinusJ(mainMinusJ, minusI, lifetime):
    result = []
    for m in mainMinusJ:
        if lifetime > 0:
            minusI.append(Index(m.i-1, m.j, m.k, lifetime))
        m.lifetime -= 1
        m.j -= 1
        if m.lifetime > 0:
            result.append(m)
    return result

def StepMainMinusI(mainMinusI, plusJ, lifetime):
    result = []
    for m in mainMinusI:
        if lifetime > 0:
            plusJ.append(Index(m.i, m.j+1, m.k, lifetime))
        m.lifetime -= 1
        m.i -= 1
        if m.lifetime > 0:
            result.append(m)
    return result

def StepMainPlusJ(mainPlusJ, plusI, lifetime):
    result = []
    for m in mainPlusJ:
        if lifetime > 0:
            plusI.append(Index(m.i+1, m.j, m.k, lifetime))
        m.lifetime -= 1
        m.j += 1
        if m.lifetime > 0:
            result.append(m)
    return result
```

Set of functions to iterate a third dimensional `K` nodes:

```
def StepMainPlusK(mainPlusK, mainPlusI, mainMinusI, mainPlusJ, mainMinusJ, lifetimeA, lifetimeB):
    result = []
    for m in mainPlusK:
        if lifetimeA > 0:
            mainPlusI.append(Index(+1, 0, m.k, lifetimeA))
            mainPlusJ.append(Index(0, +1, m.k, lifetimeA))
        if lifetimeB > 0:
            mainMinusI.append(Index(-1, 0, m.k, lifetimeB))
            mainMinusJ.append(Index(0, -1, m.k, lifetimeB))
        m.lifetime -= 1
        m.k += 1
        if m.lifetime > 0:
            result.append(m)
    return result

def StepMainMinusK(mainMinusK, mainPlusI, mainMinusI, mainPlusJ, mainMinusJ, lifetimeA, lifetimeB):
    result = []
    for m in mainMinusK:
        if lifetimeA > 0:
            mainPlusI.append(Index(+1, 0, m.k, lifetimeA))
            mainPlusJ.append(Index(0, +1, m.k, lifetimeA))
        if lifetimeB > 0:
            mainMinusI.append(Index(-1, 0, m.k, lifetimeB))
            mainMinusJ.append(Index(0, -1, m.k, lifetimeB))
        m.lifetime -= 1
        m.k -= 1
        if m.lifetime > 0:
            result.append(m)
    return result
```

These two functions have two different lifetime parameters for the case when `n` is odd and one half can be less than another. I've divided them by sign - negatively oriented will have lower half of indexes.

Set of functions to iterate `Secondary` nodes:

```
def StepPlusI(plusI):
    result = []
    for m in plusI:
        m.i += 1
        m.lifetime -= 1
        if m.lifetime > 0:
            result.append(m)
    return result

def StepMinusI(minusI):
    result = []
    for m in minusI:
        m.i -= 1
        m.lifetime -= 1
        if m.lifetime > 0:
            result.append(m)
    return result

def StepPlusJ(plusJ):
    result = []
    for m in plusJ:
        m.j += 1
        m.lifetime -= 1
        if m.lifetime > 0:
            result.append(m)
    return result

def StepMinusJ(minusJ):
    result = []
    for m in minusJ:
        m.j -= 1
        m.lifetime -= 1
        if m.lifetime > 0:
            result.append(m)
    return result
```

And the main function:

```
def Traverse(N):
    halfA = halfB = (N-1)/2
    if N % 2 == 0: # size is even
        halfA = N/2
        halfB = N/2-1

    # visit center
    Index(0,0,0,0).visit()

    # Secondary nodes
    PlusI  = []
    MinusI = []
    PlusJ  = []
    MinusJ = []

    # Main nodes
    MainPlusI  = []
    MainMinusI = []
    MainPlusJ  = []
    MainMinusJ = []
    MainPlusK  = []
    MainMinusK = []

    # Add Main nodes
    if halfA > 0:
        MainPlusI.append(  Index(+1, 0, 0, halfA) )
        MainPlusJ.append(  Index(0, +1, 0, halfA) )
        MainPlusK.append(  Index(0, 0, +1, halfA) )

    if halfB > 0:
        MainMinusI.append( Index(-1, 0, 0, halfB) )
        MainMinusJ.append( Index(0, -1, 0, halfB) )
        MainMinusK.append( Index(0, 0, -1, halfB) )

    # Finish condition flag
    visited = True
    while visited:
        visited = False

        # visit all Main nodes
        for m in MainPlusI:
            m.visit()
            visited = True
        for m in MainMinusI:
            m.visit()
            visited = True
        for m in MainPlusJ:
            m.visit()
            visited = True
        for m in MainMinusJ:
            m.visit()
            visited = True
        for m in MainPlusK:
            m.visit()
            visited = True
        for m in MainMinusK:
            m.visit()
            visited = True

        # Visit all Secondary nodes
        for m in PlusI:
            m.visit()
            visited = True
        for m in MinusI:
            m.visit()
            visited = True
        for m in PlusJ:
            m.visit()
            visited = True
        for m in MinusJ:
            m.visit()
            visited = True

        # Iterate Secondary nodes first
        PlusI = StepPlusI(PlusI)
        MinusI = StepMinusI(MinusI)
        PlusJ = StepPlusJ(PlusJ)
        MinusJ = StepMinusJ(MinusJ)

        # Iterate all Main nodes as they might generate Secondary nodes
        MainPlusI = StepMainPlusI(MainPlusI, MinusJ, halfB)
        MainMinusJ = StepMainMinusJ(MainMinusJ, MinusI, halfB)
        MainMinusI = StepMainMinusI(MainMinusI, PlusJ, halfA)
        MainPlusJ = StepMainPlusJ(MainPlusJ, PlusI, halfA)

        # Iterate K nodes last as they might produce Main nodes
        MainPlusK = StepMainPlusK(MainPlusK, MainPlusI, MainMinusI, MainPlusJ, MainMinusJ, halfA, halfB)
        MainMinusK = StepMainMinusK(MainMinusK, MainPlusI, MainMinusI, MainPlusJ, MainMinusJ, halfA, halfB)
```

And the live example [<kbd>Code</kbd>](http://ideone.com/A7q3Qs)

Answer (score 5):

**Octant symmetry**

The cells in a cubic matrix which are at a certain Manhattan-distance from the center form an octahedron, which is symmetrical about the xy, xz and yz planes going through the center of the cube.

[image: distance 3 in a 9x9x9 matrix]

This means that you only need to find the cells which form one face of the octahedron, in the first [octant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octant_(solid_geometry)) of the cube, and mirror them to get the cells in the other 7 octants. So the problem is reduced to traversing the first octant of the cube (which itself is a cube) diagonally, from the center (distance 0) to the corner cell (maximum distance = 3 × n/2).

[image: distance 3 in the first octant]

**Algorithm to find coordinates**

Finding the cells which are at a certain Manhattan-distance from the (0,0,0) cell in the first octant (i.e. the cells which form one face of the octahedron, perpendicular to the diagonal of the cube), means finding cells whose coordinates (x,y,z) sum to that distance. So, in the example of a 5x5x5 octant, the cells at distance 3 are the cells with coordinates:

> (3,0,0)  (2,1,0)  (1,2,0)  (0,3,0)
>   (2,0,1)  (1,1,1)  (0,2,1)
>   (1,0,2)  (0,1,2)
>   (0,0,3)

You'll notice the similarity to a partitioning of the distance (actually, it's a so-called [weak composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) with a bounded length of 3).

Finding these combinations can be easily achieved with three nested loops; the only complication is that the distance in each dimension is restricted to n/2, so you have to skip values for x and/or y for which there exists no value for z so that x, y and z sum to the distance; that is what the `min()` and `max()` in the JavaScript code example, and the `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin` and `ymax` variables in the C code example are for.

The mirroring of the cells in an even-sized cube is straightforward; in an odd-sized cube, the cells are not mirrored in the dimension for which their coordinate is zero (i.e. when the cell lies in the plane of symmetry). That is what the checks whether x, y or z equal zero are for in the code examples.

**Parallel programming**

I don't know much about GPU programming, but I assume you can completely parallellise the algorithm. For every iteration of the outer loop (i.e. for every distance), once the minimum and maximum value of x has been calculated, the iterations with different values of x can be run in parallel. Then for each value of x, once the minimum and maximum value of y has been calculated, the iterations with different values of y can be run in parallel. And finally, for each coordinate set of (x,y,z) the mirroring to the other octants can be run in parallel.

**Code example 1 (JavaScript)**

*(Run the code snippet to see the inside-out traversal of a 9x9x9 matrix as shown in the diagrams.)*

```js
function insideOut(n) {
    var half = Math.ceil(n / 2) - 1;
    for (var d = 0; d <= 3 * half; d++) {
        for (var x = Math.max(0, d - 2 * half); x <= Math.min(half, d); x++) {
            for (var y = Math.max(0, d - x - half); y <= Math.min(half, d - x); y++) {
                document.write("<br>distance " + d + " (&plusmn;" + x + ",&plusmn;" + y + ",&plusmn;" + (d - x - y) + ") &rarr; ");
                n % 2 ? mirrorOdd(x, y, d - x - y) : mirrorEven(x, y, d - x - y);
            }
        }
    }
    function mirrorEven(x, y, z) {
        for (var i = 1; i >= 0; --i, x *= -1) {
            for (var j = 1; j >= 0; --j, y *= -1) {
                for (var k = 1; k >= 0; --k, z *= -1) {
                    visit(half + x + i, half + y + j, half + z + k);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    function mirrorOdd(x, y, z) {
        for (var i = 0; i < (x ? 2 : 1); ++i, x *= -1) {
            for (var j = 0; j < (y ? 2 : 1); ++j, y *= -1) {
                for (var k = 0; k < (z ? 2 : 1); ++k, z *= -1) {
                    visit(half + x, half + y, half + z);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    function visit(x, y, z) {
        document.write("(" + x + "," + y + "," + z + ") " );
    }
}
insideOut(9);
```

**Code example 2 (C)**

The mirroring functions can be unrolled for simplicity. In fact, the whole algorithm consists of nothing more than 3 nested loops and simple integer calculations.

```c
void mirrorEven(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int z, unsigned int h) {
    visit(h+x+1, h+y+1, h+z+1);
    visit(h+x+1, h+y+1, h-z);
    visit(h+x+1, h-y,   h+z+1);
    visit(h+x+1, h-y,   h-z);
    visit(h-x,   h+y+1, h+z+1);
    visit(h-x,   h+y+1, h-z);
    visit(h-x,   h-y,   h+z+1);
    visit(h-x,   h-y,   h-z);
}
void mirrorOdd(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int z, unsigned int h) {
                     visit(h+x, h+y, h+z);
    if (          z) visit(h+x, h+y, h-z);
    if (     y     ) visit(h+x, h-y, h+z);
    if (     y && z) visit(h+x, h-y, h-z);
    if (x          ) visit(h-x, h+y, h+z);
    if (x      && z) visit(h-x, h+y, h-z);
    if (x && y     ) visit(h-x, h-y, h+z);
    if (x && y && z) visit(h-x, h-y, h-z);
}
void insideOut(unsigned int n) {
    unsigned int d, x, xmin, xmax, y, ymin, ymax, half = (n-1)/2;
    for (d = 0; d <= 3*half; d++) {
        xmin = d < 2*half ? 0 : d-2*half;
        xmax = d < half ? d : half;
        for (x = xmin; x <= xmax; x++) {
            ymin = d < x+half ? 0 : d-x-half;
            ymax = d > x+half ? half : d-x;
            for (y = ymin; y <= ymax; y++) {
                if (n%2) mirrorOdd(x, y, d-x-y, half);
                else mirrorEven(x, y, d-x-y, half);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The key to getting an efficient algorithm to this question is to see the geometry underlying it. What you are asking for is to solve the [Diophantine equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation) N = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 for each successive value of N, enumerating such solutions in any order. The solutions to this equation are integral points on a sphere of radius N. So in one sense your problem is enumerating spheres.

First, though, it should be clear that the hard problem here is enumerating nonnegative solutions for coordinates (a,b,c). For each such coordinate, there are eight other solutions from mirror symmetry around the coordinate planes, since a^2 = (-a)^2 etc. (In general. If one or more of a,b,c are zero, you get fewer mirror points.) There's a further symmetry by permuting the coordinates so that a <= b <= c. This is the easy part of the enumeration.

The essence of the sphere enumeration algorithm is to consider two sets of points that approximate a sphere of radius N: one which is consists of points with norm "slightly less" than N and one which consists of their lattice neighbors with norm "slightly greater" than N or equal to N. "Slightly less" means that for a point (a,b,c), a^2 + b^2 + c^2 < N, but one or more of the points (a+1,b,c), (a,b+1,c), or (a,b,c+1) has norm >= N. As far as code, you don't need to represent the "slightly less" set; it's already been processed. It's sufficient to create a heap of the "slightly greater" set, sorted by their norm.

Each step of the algorithm changes to the "slightly greater" set for N into one for N+1. Remove the least element of the heap, say, (a,b,c). Now add its nearest neighbor points with greater norm to the heap, the three points (a+1,b,c), (a,b+1,c), and (a,b,c+1). Some of them may already be there; I'll come back to that. When you add an incremental point onto the heap, you need its norm. You do *not*, however, need to calculate it from scratch. Rely on the identity (a+1)^2 - a^2 = 2a + 1. In other words, you don't need any multiplication operations to compute these norms. Depending on your GPU, you can compute expressions a << 1 + 1 or maybe a + a + 1.

You can also optimize checking for existing points on the heap. Each point has six immediate lattice neighbors. The lattice neighbor with the least norm will be the first one to add it. Suppose a < b < c for a point (a,b,c). Its neighbor with the least norm is (a,b,c-1). Thus when enumerating the point (a-1,b,c), the point (a,b,c) is already on the heap; you don't need even to check that it's there. Pay attention to special cases where the some of the coordinates are equal.

This algorithm enumerates spheres, not cubes. It's easy enough to restrict attention to a cube of with maximum index D. If one of the coordinates is equal to D, then don't add three points, but fewer. The enumeration ends on the point (D,D,D), when there are no more valid neighbor points to add.

The performance of this algorithm should be very fast. It needs a heap of size O(N^2). If you enumerate all the points beforehand you need storage O(N^3). Furthermore, it needs no multiplication, for a further constant speed up.

Answer (score 2):

If it is just centers: There are a lot of different valid orders. Just compute a 3d map, with elements sorted in order. Offset by origin. Make the map:

```
for x,y,z -domain, domain
  map.add ( x,y,z, distance(x,y,z) ) 
map.sort ( distance )
```

Then at point x,y,z to traverse

```
for ( i=0; i++ )
   visit ( map[i].xyz + x,y,z )
```

If it's real distance and not voxel centers, it gets a lot harder.

Comment: This is a valid solution, although it is some sort of precalculated lookup table which does not fit my requirements (calculating the map on the fly is no option either, since this takes too much time to process).

Comment: @Dual: Why does the map not work for you? Honestly curious. I would do some kind of spiral then... but you will visit the same cell multiple times and possibly not visit all cells. If you do not care for the distance metric, look up z-order/morton curves. Do one per quadrant.

Comment: Yes, reading some other answers you really just want a z order curve. Do it for every quadrant. Z Order is z(i) = ( every3rdbit(i),  every3rdbit(i>>1),  every3rdbit(i>>2) )  with every3rdbit (x) ( y=0; for(64) y+=(x&1); y<<1; x>>3;

Answer (score 2):

generating indexes in **Manhatan distance** order is similar to **subset sum** problem so just compute the max distance (the sum) and then separate axises to reduce the problem. Here **C++** example:

```cpp
int x,y,z,d,dx,dy,dz,D;
// center idx
int cx=n>>1;
int cy=n>>1;
int cz=n>>1;
// min idx
int x0=-cx;
int y0=-cy;
int z0=-cz;
// max idx
int x1=n-1-cx;
int y1=n-1-cy;
int z1=n-1-cz;
// max distance
x=max(x0,x1);
y=max(y0,y1);
z=max(z0,z1);
D=x+y+z;
// here do your stuff
#define traverse(x,y,z) { /* do something with the array beware x,y,z are signed !!!  */ }
// traversal
for (d=0;d<=D;d++)  // distance
 for (dx=d              ,x=-dx;x<=dx;x++) if ((x>=x0)&&(x<=x1)) // x axis separation
 for (dy=d-abs(x)       ,y=-dy;y<=dy;y++) if ((y>=y0)&&(y<=y1)) // y axis separation
    {
    dz=d-abs(x)-abs(y); // z axis have only 1 or 2 options
    z=-dz; if       (z>=z0)  traverse(x,y,z);
    z=+dz; if ((z)&&(z<=z1)) traverse(x,y,z);
    }
#undef traverse
```

You can replace the `traverse(x,y,z)` macro by any stuff or function you want. beware `x,y,z` are signed so can be negative to get **C++** style indexes you need to use `(x+cx,y+cy,z+cz)`.

This can handle booth even and odd indexes and also non cube resolutions (if you simply convert `n` to `nx,ny,nz` in the first few constants computations). Also the `[0,0,0]` can be everywhere (not in center) so it is easily applicable to any needs I can think of...

Here example output for `n=5`

```
[ 0, 0, 0] = 0
[-1, 0, 0] = 1
[ 0,-1, 0] = 1
[ 0, 0,-1] = 1
[ 0, 0, 1] = 1
[ 0, 1, 0] = 1
[ 1, 0, 0] = 1
[-2, 0, 0] = 2
[-1,-1, 0] = 2
[-1, 0,-1] = 2
[-1, 0, 1] = 2
[-1, 1, 0] = 2
[ 0,-2, 0] = 2
[ 0,-1,-1] = 2
[ 0,-1, 1] = 2
[ 0, 0,-2] = 2
[ 0, 0, 2] = 2
[ 0, 1,-1] = 2
[ 0, 1, 1] = 2
[ 0, 2, 0] = 2
[ 1,-1, 0] = 2
[ 1, 0,-1] = 2
[ 1, 0, 1] = 2
[ 1, 1, 0] = 2
[ 2, 0, 0] = 2
[-2,-1, 0] = 3
[-2, 0,-1] = 3
[-2, 0, 1] = 3
[-2, 1, 0] = 3
[-1,-2, 0] = 3
[-1,-1,-1] = 3
[-1,-1, 1] = 3
[-1, 0,-2] = 3
[-1, 0, 2] = 3
[-1, 1,-1] = 3
[-1, 1, 1] = 3
[-1, 2, 0] = 3
[ 0,-2,-1] = 3
[ 0,-2, 1] = 3
[ 0,-1,-2] = 3
[ 0,-1, 2] = 3
[ 0, 1,-2] = 3
[ 0, 1, 2] = 3
[ 0, 2,-1] = 3
[ 0, 2, 1] = 3
[ 1,-2, 0] = 3
[ 1,-1,-1] = 3
[ 1,-1, 1] = 3
[ 1, 0,-2] = 3
[ 1, 0, 2] = 3
[ 1, 1,-1] = 3
[ 1, 1, 1] = 3
[ 1, 2, 0] = 3
[ 2,-1, 0] = 3
[ 2, 0,-1] = 3
[ 2, 0, 1] = 3
[ 2, 1, 0] = 3
[-2,-2, 0] = 4
[-2,-1,-1] = 4
[-2,-1, 1] = 4
[-2, 0,-2] = 4
[-2, 0, 2] = 4
[-2, 1,-1] = 4
[-2, 1, 1] = 4
[-2, 2, 0] = 4
[-1,-2,-1] = 4
[-1,-2, 1] = 4
[-1,-1,-2] = 4
[-1,-1, 2] = 4
[-1, 1,-2] = 4
[-1, 1, 2] = 4
[-1, 2,-1] = 4
[-1, 2, 1] = 4
[ 0,-2,-2] = 4
[ 0,-2, 2] = 4
[ 0, 2,-2] = 4
[ 0, 2, 2] = 4
[ 1,-2,-1] = 4
[ 1,-2, 1] = 4
[ 1,-1,-2] = 4
[ 1,-1, 2] = 4
[ 1, 1,-2] = 4
[ 1, 1, 2] = 4
[ 1, 2,-1] = 4
[ 1, 2, 1] = 4
[ 2,-2, 0] = 4
[ 2,-1,-1] = 4
[ 2,-1, 1] = 4
[ 2, 0,-2] = 4
[ 2, 0, 2] = 4
[ 2, 1,-1] = 4
[ 2, 1, 1] = 4
[ 2, 2, 0] = 4
[-2,-2,-1] = 5
[-2,-2, 1] = 5
[-2,-1,-2] = 5
[-2,-1, 2] = 5
[-2, 1,-2] = 5
[-2, 1, 2] = 5
[-2, 2,-1] = 5
[-2, 2, 1] = 5
[-1,-2,-2] = 5
[-1,-2, 2] = 5
[-1, 2,-2] = 5
[-1, 2, 2] = 5
[ 1,-2,-2] = 5
[ 1,-2, 2] = 5
[ 1, 2,-2] = 5
[ 1, 2, 2] = 5
[ 2,-2,-1] = 5
[ 2,-2, 1] = 5
[ 2,-1,-2] = 5
[ 2,-1, 2] = 5
[ 2, 1,-2] = 5
[ 2, 1, 2] = 5
[ 2, 2,-1] = 5
[ 2, 2, 1] = 5
[-2,-2,-2] = 6
[-2,-2, 2] = 6
[-2, 2,-2] = 6
[-2, 2, 2] = 6
[ 2,-2,-2] = 6
[ 2,-2, 2] = 6
[ 2, 2,-2] = 6
[ 2, 2, 2] = 6
```

Answer (score 1):

The distance from the origin is known for each point `(a, b, c)` to be `sqrt(a*a + b*b + c*c)`. We can define this to be `distance(a, b, c)`.<sup>†</sup>

For each point in your 3D array, you can insert it into a [min heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) using `distance` as your ordering criteria. To avoid recalculation, augment your point representation in the heap to include the cached calculation of `distance` for that point when it was inserted into the heap.

> heap_element = (x, y, z, d)
>
> heap_compare(heap_element a, heap_element b) = a.d < b.d
>
> for each point (x,y,z) in 3D array
>   **·** heap.add(heap_element(x, y, z, distance(x, y, z)))

Now, you can just draw out each point from the top of the heap to get your ordering.

> N = heap.size
>   for i in 0..N
>   **·** ordering[i] = heap.top
>   **·** heap.pop

<sub>† For the purposes of this algorithm, using the actual distance is not critical. For performance reasons, you can omit taking the `sqrt`, and just use `a*a + b*b + c*c` as the metric for the heap ordering criteria.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

In ruby, I just get all points for each distance from the center in order.

```
def get_points(side_len)
  side_len % 2 == 0 ? min_dist = 1 : min_dist = 0

  if side_len % 2 == 0
    min_dist = 1
    max_1d_dist = side_len / 2
  else
    min_dist = 0
    max_1d_dist = (side_len - 1) / 2
  end

  max_dist = 3 * max_1d_dist

  min_dist.upto(max_dist) do |dist|
    min_x_dist = [min_dist, dist - 2 * max_1d_dist].max
    max_x_dist = [dist - 2 * min_dist, max_1d_dist].min
    min_x_dist.upto(max_x_dist) do |x_dist|
      min_y_dist = [min_dist, dist - x_dist - max_1d_dist].max
      max_y_dist = [dist - x_dist - min_dist, max_1d_dist].min
      min_y_dist.upto(max_y_dist) do |y_dist|
        z_dist = dist - x_dist - y_dist
        print_vals(x_dist, y_dist, z_dist)
      end
    end
  end
end

def print_vals(x_dist, y_dist, z_dist)
  x_signs = [1]
  y_signs = [1]
  z_signs = [1]
  x_signs << -1 unless x_dist == 0
  y_signs << -1 unless y_dist == 0
  z_signs << -1 unless z_dist == 0

  x_signs.each do |x_sign|
    y_signs.each do |y_sign|
      z_signs.each do |z_sign|
        puts "[#{x_sign*x_dist}, #{y_sign*y_dist}, #{z_sign*z_dist}]"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Output is:

```
2.1.2 :277 > get_points(1)
[0, 0, 0]

2.1.2 :278 > get_points(2)
[1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, -1]
[1, -1, 1]
[1, -1, -1]
[-1, 1, 1]
[-1, 1, -1]
[-1, -1, 1]
[-1, -1, -1]

2.1.2 :279 > get_points(3)
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, -1]
[0, 1, 0]
[0, -1, 0]
[1, 0, 0]
[-1, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 1]
[0, 1, -1]
[0, -1, 1]
[0, -1, -1]
[1, 0, 1]
[1, 0, -1]
[-1, 0, 1]
[-1, 0, -1]
[1, 1, 0]
[1, -1, 0]
[-1, 1, 0]
[-1, -1, 0]
[1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, -1]
[1, -1, 1]
[1, -1, -1]
[-1, 1, 1]
[-1, 1, -1]
[-1, -1, 1]
[-1, -1, -1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a **simple** and **fast** algorithm to transverse a 3D array using **Manhattan distance**.

The 3D array with size `n` in each dimension shall be represented by a coordinate system with the origin in the middle of your array. For the centre to be defined, we assume the size of the array in each dimension is a odd number. Every element has a triple of coordinates like this `[x, y, z]` and each coordinate can reach a maximum value of `(n/2)-1. (Info: The pictures added are in 2D for better understanding)

1. First we can simplify this by regarding just the positive octant (all coordinates are positive). All other elements can be generated by reflection.

   [image]
2. In one octant all elements with the same distance to the centre are defined by a plane with the equation: `x+y+z=distance`. We achieve this by counting the distance from `0` to `n-1` in single steps. For each distance we look for all element on the corresponding plane.

   [image]
3. When reaching a `distance>(n/2)-1` some of the points will be outside the array (one of the `coord > (n/2)-1`). So we have to exclude them from the results. 

   [image]
4. Each calculated element is representing up to 8 elements you get by reflection (see point 1). You can simply achieve this by alternately multiplying each coordinate with `-1`. `[+/-x, +/-y, +/-z]` (8 possible combinations if all `coords != 0`)

   [image]

Here is a code schema for my algorithm:

```
//rise the distance by one each iteration
for(distance=0; distance<n-1; distance++) //loop distance from 0 to n-1
  for(i=0; i<=distance; i++) 
    x=i; //x ∈ [0, distance]
    for(j=0; j<=distance-x; j++) 
      y=j; //y ∈ [0, distance-x]
      z=distance-(x+y); //because distance=x+y+z
      //now we have to exclude all elements with one coord <= (n/2)-1
      if(x<=(n/2)-1 && y<=(n/2)-1 && z<=(n/2)-1)
        //[x,y,z] we found a valid element!
        //let's generate the 7 corresponding elements (up to 7)
        if(x!=0) //[-x,y,z]
        if(y!=0) //[x,-y,z]
        if(z!=0) //[x,y,-z]
        if(x!=0 && y!=0) //[-x,-y,z]
        if(x!=0 && z!=0) //[-x,y,-z]
        if(y!=0 && z!=0) //[x,-y,-z]
        if(y!=0 && y!=0 && z!=0) //[-x,-y,-z]
```

Here is the output for `n=7`:

```
Distance:0 [0,0,0] 
Distance:1 [0,0,1] [0,0,-1] [0,1,0] [0,-1,0] [1,0,0] [-1,0,0] 
Distance:2 [0,0,2] [0,0,-2] [0,1,1] [0,-1,1] [0,1,-1] [0,-1,-1] [0,2,0] [0,-2,0] [1,0,1] [-1,0,1] [1,0,-1] [-1,0,-1] [1,1,0] [-1,1,0] [1,-1,0] [-1,-1,0] [2,0,0] [-2,0,0] 
Distance:3 [0,1,2] [0,-1,2] [0,1,-2] [0,-1,-2] [0,2,1] [0,-2,1] [0,2,-1] [0,-2,-1] [1,0,2] [-1,0,2] [1,0,-2] [-1,0,-2] [1,1,1] [-1,1,1] [1,-1,1] [1,1,-1] [-1,-1,1] [-1,1,-1] [1,-1,-1] [-1,-1,-1] [1,2,0] [-1,2,0] [1,-2,0] [-1,-2,0] [2,0,1] [-2,0,1] [2,0,-1] [-2,0,-1] [2,1,0] [-2,1,0] [2,-1,0] [-2,-1,0] 
Distance:4 [0,2,2] [0,-2,2] [0,2,-2] [0,-2,-2] [1,1,2] [-1,1,2] [1,-1,2] [1,1,-2] [-1,-1,2] [-1,1,-2] [1,-1,-2] [-1,-1,-2] [1,2,1] [-1,2,1] [1,-2,1] [1,2,-1] [-1,-2,1] [-1,2,-1] [1,-2,-1] [-1,-2,-1] [2,0,2] [-2,0,2] [2,0,-2] [-2,0,-2] [2,1,1] [-2,1,1] [2,-1,1] [2,1,-1] [-2,-1,1] [-2,1,-1] [2,-1,-1] [-2,-1,-1] [2,2,0] [-2,2,0] [2,-2,0] [-2,-2,0] 
Distance:5 [1,2,2] [-1,2,2] [1,-2,2] [1,2,-2] [-1,-2,2] [-1,2,-2] [1,-2,-2] [-1,-2,-2] [2,1,2] [-2,1,2] [2,-1,2] [2,1,-2] [-2,-1,2] [-2,1,-2] [2,-1,-2] [-2,-1,-2] [2,2,1] [-2,2,1] [2,-2,1] [2,2,-1] [-2,-2,1] [-2,2,-1] [2,-2,-1]
```

If you are using Euclidian Norm, you have to replace your distance with: `sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z)` and you cannot rise the distance in steps of one. But beside that you could do it very similiar.

Answer (score 0):

Waited until the bounty race was completed, as to not interfere. I would however like to point out that imho **all answers** that i can see atm are rather dubious. The question holds this statement:

*"this algorithm is intended to perform on **GPU**"*

It is indeed possible to do efficient numeric processing on the GPU, but all solutions here propose some kind of looping. This is **not how the GPU works**.

**The GPU executes in parallel**. Indeed one can loop in the GPU, but then it happens in an extremely isolated fashion. A loop requires a "global controller", for example a counter, but the point of the GPU execution is that it executes in **no particular order**, using multiple cores. It is impossible to "grab" the result of one cores' execution and use it as argument to another cores' calculation. This is simply not how the GPU works.

It is possible to do calculation of multidimensional arrays on the GPU, even on higher than 3-dimensional. That is just a matter of cell addressing, and it is trivial to address for example 4 dimensions using a 1-dimensional address space, and describe/access the corresponding data.

But it is **not possible** to step through cells (pixels, memory locations) one by one, in a specific order - there is no control for such. And it is **not possible** to increment, or have loops, or have inner loops. On a GPU, the last element may well be executed first. On a GPU, each element is **totally autonomous**. No calculation is aware of any other calculation, since there is no communication between the them. The environment for each calculation on the GPU is as **if it was alone in the world**.

The answers given in this thread all assume **CPU** logic. IF solving the problem on CPU, it is trivial. Taking a 2-dimensional example, here are the absolute x,y coordinate pairs for 5x5, adjusted for zero in the middle:

```
┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
│2 2│2 1│2 0│2 1│2 2│
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│1 2│1 1│1 0│1 1│1 2│
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│0 2│0 1│0 0│0 1│0 2│
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│1 2│1 1│1 0│1 1│1 2│
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│2 2│2 1│2 0│2 1│2 2│
└───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘
```

Adding the pairs in each cell gives us the Manhattan distances:

```
4 3 2 3 4
3 2 1 2 3
2 1 0 1 2
3 2 1 2 3
4 3 2 3 4
```

At the same time, we can have an indexing system (this is however a weakness in the question, as it does no state adressing spaces):

```
 1  2  3  4  5
 6  7  8  9 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25
```

We can flatten both the distances:

```
dist = 4 3 2 3 4 3 2 1 2 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 2 1 2 3 4 3 2 3 4
```

and the indexes

```
index = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
```

The unique Manhattan distances for an N (or N * N or N * N * N) array are **all numbers between 1 and N-1 preceeded by 0 if N is odd**. For a 5*5 matrix:

```
0 1 2 3 4
```

Walk through each distance and see where that distance equals "dist". For 5*5:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 // dist = 0 at locations 13
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 // dist = 1 at locations 8 12 14 18
0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 // dist = 2 at locations 3 7 9 11 15 17 19 23
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 // dist = 3 at locations 2 4 6 10 16 20 22 24
1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 // dist = 4 at locations 1 5 21 25
```

and build up an array based on those locations. Ie. have an ampty array, append 13 to it as it's first element, then append 8 12 14 18, etc. The eventual result will be

```
13 8 12 14 18 3 7 9 11 15 17 19 23 2 4 6 10 16 20 22 24 1 5 21 25
```

That is the desired sord order. It is simple to re-arrange that into for example 2-dimensional address space, by using divide, min and residue.

**However, this way to calculate is USELESS ON A GPU.** It requires a specific execution order, and that **we do not have on a GPU**.

If solving the traversal order on a GPU, the solution should be

lookupcoordinates = fn(currentposition)

It may be possible to describe fn, but the question is way too incomplete - a whole lot more detail is required, than just saying "on GPU". How is the 3d array described? In what memory is it situated? What is the result's adressing space? Etc.

I'd be happy to hear more insight detail on this, as well as corrections to what i write above.

---

Addendum for discussion with user [m69](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4907604/m69)

One (minor) thought is doing the calculation in [number of dimensions] steps, where an accumulation from previous dimension would be used for next, up to for example 3. It may be that the numerical behaviour would be useful in such a case.

If looking closer at the basics, one would probably assume a linear target space, such that it is a simple indexing vector from 1 to [number of cells], where for example a 10*10*10 cube would have a linear 1D vector of 1000 indexes, from 1 to 1000. It is always possible to later on re-phrase these indexes into square or more-dimensional format.

In a 1-dimensional case, let's assume we have a 9-element data "cube" (same as 9*1*1, if expressed 3-dimensionally). Would be as below

```
x x x x x x x x x // Data
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 // Indexes
4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 // Manhattan distances
5 4 6 3 7 2 8 1 9 // Pick order, starting from center
```

Hence we need a **fn** that maps as below

```
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│1 to 5│2 to 4│3 to 6│4 to 3│5 to 7│6 to 2│7 to 8│8 to 1│9 to 9│
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

Now, if for example looking at index 4 of the result, fn must be able to, independently of any other index, resolve a result = 3, ie. **fn(4) = 3**. It should be possible to describe fn. It should be possible to first conclude that "4" resides in layer 2 (if layer 0 is the innermost). After that, it should be possible to conclude how meny cells layer 2 has (all layers have 2 cells), and finally whether this cell is the first or second occurance/element of layer 2. That would resolve into 3, ie. for result[4] we pick data[3].

Now, if assuming a 2-dimensional "cube" of size 11*11(*1), we have this situation:

```
0 1 2  3  4  5  6  7  8 9 10 // Unique Manhattan distances
1 4 8 12 16 20 20 16 12 8  4 // How many cells in each distance-layer?
```

We note that the "how many" is rather symmetrical, and even more symmetrical for 10*10:

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8   9 // Unique Manhattan distances
4  8 12 16 20 16 12  8   4 // How many cells in each distance-layer?
4 12 24 40 60 76 88 96 100 // Cumulative sum of "How many..."
```

Notice the "cumulative sum"! Using that, if we are atm solving for example index=55 (can happen at any time, before or after 54, remember!), we can conclude that we are currently aiming at layer 5, which holds 20 elements, those with index = 40...60.

This layer starts with 40, and we are now at 55. Difference is 15. Maybe it is possible to describe the **offset** (x,y)-coordinates from "layer 5-origin x,y) using that "15"? My guess is that we are just entering the 4th quadrant.

Same for 3D?

Comment: We can indeed not control the global order of execution, but when it comes to the execution of a single kernel, we can control the order each kernel accesses its neighbours (if needed) or arbitrary memory. You're however right that this might not be the optimal solution since this approach might bring up branch- and data divergence, limiting the GPUs performance. Some of the given answers (including the accepted one) dealing with for loops might get unrolled at compiletime when using constant values which will at least eliminate branch divergence.

Comment: It's true that loops get unolled, usually by default. But that loop still residen inside a single core (or iteration, kernel). To get the advantage of GPU parallellism, all iterations (w or w/o internal loops) should execute simultaneously, and yet perform correctly. I have coded a lot of GPGPU, and my immediate reaction was to pre-calculate the sort order offline, and the (re)use it as needed. The weakness there is ofc if the data varies much in size. I however DO think there is a way to describe a direct __lookup=fn(x,y,z)__, it's just not simple to resolve fn. But i am sure it does exist.

Comment: So would a GPU way of doing something with certain cells in a 3D array be to create a second 3D array which acts as a mask, and then combine them? And could you create every 2D layer in such a mask from the previous 2D layer with some kind of "neighbouring pixel" method?

Comment: Yes to the 1st, no to the 2nd. Commonly processing on the GPU can involve a few help steps, these are "intermediate stage calculations", but one must notice that they also happen in parallel. Ie. one step can be "calculate the full set A", another "full set B" and the final calc then C=fn(A, B). But you cannot access a "neighboring partial result" in C while you resolve C (as there is no execution order, and C is in "write only" state re. itself), and this causes the big challenge. However you can access anything in A and/or B while calculating C. Continues...

Comment: If i understand the challenge correctly, this is actually about converting addressing from one space to another. Converting between a 1-dimensional and 2-dimensional is simple, like 1,2,3,... to (1,1),(1,2)(2,1).... But this is (i guess) more like converting from an ascending  1-dimensional (or at least square) to an "ascending octahedron layered" space, when "ascending" means "innermost layer first" in addition to an existing (though arbitrary) incrementing order at each layer surface. Tricky indeed :-) (Edit: And note, your solution is excellent, just not quite inside this tricky box :-))

Comment: Once you have the 3D array with the octahedron-shaped mask for a certain distance d, then most of this mask can be re-used for distance d-1 or d+1. Problem is, you have to move or copy 2D arrays up or down one step, and insert or remove one in the middle, which requires accessing them individually and sequentially. So is it completely impossible to treat a 3D array as an array of 2D arrays in a GPU? (Or alternatively, can you combine part of one 3D array with a specific part of another 3D array?)

Comment: As the GPU is called, it solves "one full set", which is hopefully large (eg. a million cells). Naturally, you can call it again, as many times you wish, and have an accumulated result "walk through" the entire say 100 iterations. It IS possible to treat a 3D arrays as 2D, or 1D, or nD in the GPU - that's just a matter of addressing. Natively it "knows" 1D, 2D and 3D. But to use a previous result (= the million just calc'ed), one would have to write it out, then re-start the entire process with a slightly modified global parm that is identical to ALL individual cell iterations. Cont...

Comment: Think of pixel A=(100,100) at your screen. You can NOT first calculate pixel B=(150, 100) and then use that result for A, because 1) B may not yet be calculated and 2) there is no way to read B. That's why one would have to create a __fn__, so that when painting pixel/solving cell (1,1), fn points at the center of the octahedron. Then when solving (2,1)...(5,1), fn points at the 4 cells with Manhattan distance=1 in turn (now assuming 2D).  (6,1)...(9,1) would point at Manhattan distance=2 cells, etc. Directly, with no accumulation or recursion. Cont..

Comment: One CAN accumulate by bouncing between 2 surfaces (calc this one, use the other as argument, then vice versa, swapping n times), but that contradicts the parallellism of the GPU, as it becomes a loop.

Comment: (See image I added under my answer) Would it be possible to - once you have created the nxnx2n-1 array shown in the middle - use parts of it as a mask on an nxnxn array? In the example, you'd first combine 2 layers with the bottom 2 layers of the 3D array, and then 2 layers with the top 2 layers of the 3D array, as a mask for distance 5. The example underneath shows  the two steps for distance 3. You'd be able to process every distance in two steps, without having to change anything to the mask inbetween distances.

Comment: This is excellent thinking, because it aims for parallell execution. I didn't exactly understand the calculation but i can intuitively feel the goal. A weakness is however that it still requires 2 iterations per layer, ie. a loop. Also, one must remember that the same calculation will be performed for every cell, also cells outside the current layer (can early exit though), and this happens during each iteration. I'll add a little to my answer, a general thought of how to solve this.

Comment: @Stormwind you pinned the problem exactly in your comments! I will update the question so if any other people want to contribute to this topic.

Comment: Thanks for answering my questions. I'm not sure there's much point in my continuing to work on my answer, because at every stage I'd have to come and ask you "is this possible on a GPU?". I should probably leave it to the people who know what they're talking about :-)